# Why did Andersson waste two tempi in this game?

Tags: positional-play

[Andersson gives Karpov two tempi](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1019420) (Na6-b4-a6-b4). Understandably, he moved his knight to b4 initially to attack the white bishop. But then he moved it back and forth! It was **the 32nd move** when he did this, so it is possible that it was due to time. Is there a subtler intention?

Answer (score 2):

`Na6-b4-a6-b4` was a waiting strategy. Black lacked counterplay in the position, and there wasn't much else to do. ...Nxf3+ was a possibility but it would just open the g-file for White's rook.

Comment: Why didn't he just exchange his light-squared bishop with the g6 knight, making it more difficult for white to break into the kingside?

Answer (score 0):

In "Anatoly Karpov: My 300 Best Games" Karpov gives 31...Nb4?! as a dubious move, and suggests 31...Rb4 instead, with the clear idea that Bxb4 cxb4 and Nc5 gives black a bind on the queenside.